# How to implement Push Notifications in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I have a current Mobile Application which is being developed in PhoneGap. I need to implement Push Notifications in it. The Push Notifications should be in such a way that i have a Admin Panel at the back-end developed in Asp.net and i should be able to send Push Notifications to all the devices which have my mobile app installed. The Push Notifications should be for all the 3 platforms (Windows Phone, iOS, Android). Please provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

use push-plugin follow the instruction,  and use [this](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017) for the backend PHP . this is for android, before you start all this thing, go reg at google cloud massenger(GSM) use [this](http://devgirl.org/tag/cordova-push-notifications/) site. there is bunch of tutorial to implement push plugin features. Good Luck